# How does one switch between windows on VIM?

Tags: mac, unix, vim, macvim

I'm using both Vim and MacVim (or well, trying to). I installed the [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) plugin but find it impossible to switch to the actual Tagbar window to make my selection.

I've been reading loads about window switching in VIM, found a lot of default keybindings (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>), tried setting my own. NONE worked.

I always use VIM for quick file edits and got intrigued by using it as my full-time IDE. After spending a full hour just trying to figure out how to switch a window I'm totally turned off by the idea though. Still, I feel I have to know. How do you switch the window? Am I being totally blind here?

Comment: Vim is one of those tools where everything makes perfect sense - after you know about it. Before then it may as well be in welsh.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> followed by <kbd>W</kbd> to toggle between open windows and,

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> followed by <kbd>H</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd> to move to the *left/bottom/top/right* window accordingly,

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> followed by <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> arrow to move to the *left/bottom/top/right* window accordingly.

Comment: Nope, not doing anything.

Comment: Ugh, I was pressing them at the same time. Tried Ctrl+W, THEN (seperately) one of the last keys and it worked. Sigh. Thanks!

Comment: Besides the H/J/K/L directional keys you can also hit W again (with or without Control) to switch back and forth between the previously focused window.

Comment: I get "E784: Cannot close last tab page"

Comment: The arrow keys can also be used besides `h/j/k/l`.

Comment: You can also add prefix the direction with a number if you need to go more than one window; e.g. `C-w` `2k`

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> twice does the trick for me on Macbook Pro.

Comment: It does also work on Linux.

Comment: This is the only thing that's worked for me on OSX. None of those <C-w><h/j/k/l> or <C-w><C-h/j/k/l> things the internet says does anything. Too bad <C-w><C-w> only cycles through the windows rather than going directly...

Comment: Control + W sucks when running a terminal in a browser

Comment: Running a terminal in a browser... interesting. Btw. if it sucks, you can remap it to a different keys.

Comment: Surprisingly it worked on vim in termux(android terminal emulator.).

Answer (score 17):

It's possible to remap these to a more convenient keys (i.e. instead of <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> followed by <kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd>)

Add this to your .vimrc

```
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W>h
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W>j
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W>k
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W>l
```

After that, <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> will switch window focus.

Comment: This is nice. I placed it into my vimrc.

Comment: This is clutch for those running a terminal in a browser (as mentioned in another comment) since Ctrl+W on Windows is "close window". Oof.

Comment: ❤️ that one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These mappings allow **cycling** through the windows. Whereas something like `<C-W>l` stops at the most right window `<C-w>w` moves the focus to the the first window.

In your .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>W
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>w
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).