# How to switch windows in Vim in Windows (the OS)?

Tags: windows, vim

I've read that Ctrl-W + hjkl switches windows in Vim from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/280500/how-does-one-switch-between-windows-on-vim), but when I try that it simply closes my terminal. I'm on Windows and using vim on a remote account in my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Git Bash inside Console2, and Console2 had Ctrl+W bound to "close tab".